# Decrypting message form backend with error: BadPaddingException

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, encryption

Hello I have a simple RSA private and public key, I send the public key to backend to encrypt a text and return the encrypted text back to be decrypted. Here is client side code:

SWIFT FRONT END

```
  func createPK(uid: String) {
        do {
            let keyPair = try SwiftyRSA.generateRSAKeyPair(sizeInBits: 2048)
            let privateKey = keyPair.privateKey
            let publicKey = keyPair.publicKey
      
            let aa = try publicKey.pemString()
          
           print(aa)
      
            
         
             AF.request("http://localhost:5001/cakes-delight/us-central1/encryption", method: .post, parameters: ["publicKey" : aa]).responseJSON { (result) in
                 if let err = result.error {
                     
                     print("error req \(err)")
                     return
                 }
                 if let statusCode = result.response?.statusCode {
                     if statusCode != 200 {
                         print("err: \(statusCode)")
                         return
                     }
                 }
                 
                 if let result = result.value {
                     if let JSON = result as? NSDictionary {
                         if let id = JSON["res"] as? String {
                   
                            do {
                                print("\n\nENCRYPTED?: \(id)\n\n")
                                var k = id
                                
                                let encrypted = try EncryptedMessage(base64Encoded: k.toBase64())
                                print("aa")
                                let clear = try encrypted.decrypted(with: privateKey, padding: .PKCS1)
                                print("bb")
                                let string = try clear.string(encoding: .utf8)
                               print("\n\nDECRYPTED : \(string)\n\n")
                                 return
                            } catch let error{
                                
                          
                                    print("failed \(error)")
                                    return
                            }
                           
                         }
                     }
                     
                 }
                
             }
           
        } catch {
            print("err")
        }
        
       
        
        
    }
```

TYPESCRIPT BACKEND Code:

```
export const encryption = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {
    try {
        console.log(request.body["publicKey"])
    //     let key = await new NodeRSA('-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n'+
    // request.body["publicKey"] +
    // '-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----'); 
    let key = await new NodeRSA(
    request.body["publicKey"] ); 
     
    let v = key.encrypt("i am coco!", "base64")
    console.log(v)
    let responseJSON = {
        res: v
    }
    response.status(200).send(responseJSON);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    
  });
```

SwiftyRSA gives me this error: "chunkDecryptFailed(index: 0)".

I tested my key on a RSA Encryption website 8gwifi. I used the encrypted message coming from my backend and try to decrypt it to get a better error.

I get:

```
SYSTEM Error Error Performing RSA Encryption javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
```

Comment: What padding did you use on backend-, frontend- and 8gwifi-side? This is the reson why most RSA en-/decryption fails, especially when not specifing any padding but using "default" options.

Comment: @MichaelFehr hello.  i import the public key into nodeRSA i use pkcs1-public.  i was using swiftRSA pkcs1 when drcrypting the encrypted msg sent from node. I fixed my problem by having swiftRSA (frontend) to use OAEP padding to decrypt. Can you explain why this work?

Comment: See documentation of Node-RSA (https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa/blob/master/README.md): padding scheme for encrypt/decrypt. Can be 'pkcs1_oaep' or 'pkcs1'. **Default 'pkcs1_oaep'** - that's why swiftRSA needs 'OEAP' :-). Good to read you found a working solution.

Comment: @MichaelFehr thanks. ill take a read. Do you think using 2048 rsa to send json data containing user private info in strings between 50-500 characters a good idea? I will parse the info to display in views. Do you think it will affect user experience?

Comment: Sorry but I do not have any experience in this kind of question - I'm just trying to help in programming questions :-) ... but keep in mind that RSA en-/decryption in general is often named "slow"

Comment: 500 character that makes 4000-bit! [1) OAEP-size](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100/18298) [2) PKCS#1 v1.5 padding-size](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32558/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka ok. looks like nodeRSA uses oaep padding, even though i specify the public key is using pkcs1. oh well. it works so its cool

Comment: RSAES-OAEP is in PKCS#1 see [RFC 8017](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017). What you need is the RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 and in general, it is called PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.